# How do I remove replication from old Exchange Server 2007?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, public-folders

I migrated all my mailboxes, OAB, etc to a new Exchange 2007 Server (from 2007) last week.  The only issue I'm having now is uninstalling the old Exchange from the server so I can shut down. When I try I get the error:

```
    Mailbox Role Checks              ......................... FAILED
     Uninstall cannot continue. Database 'Public Folder Database': The public fo
lder database "EXCHSVR2007\Second Storage Group\Public Folder Database" is t
he default public folder database for the following mailbox database(s):
EXCHSVR2007\First Storage Group\Mailbox Database
EXCHSVR2007\First Storage Group\second
. Before deleting the public folder database, assign a new public folder databas
e to the mailbox database(s).
```

I tried pointing the old mailbox store to the new public folder store on the new server and when I try again it gives me this error:

```
        Mailbox Role Checks              ......................... FAILED
     Uninstall cannot continue. Database 'Public Folder Database': The public fo
lder database "PXE-EXCHSVR2007\Second Storage Group\Public Folder Database" cont
ains folder replicas. Before deleting the public folder database, remove the fol
ders or move the replicas to another public folder database. For detailed instru
ctions about how to remove a public folder database, see http://go.microsoft.com
/fwlink/?linkid=81409.
```

I've run the `MoveAllReplicas` script last week. I'm not sure how else to remove the replicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out after hours of searching and testing.  I had to use ADSI Edit to remove the public folder store from the domain, then I was able to successfully uninstall the old exchange server.   It may not be pretty, but it worked:

In `ADSIEdit`, go to `Configuration`, `Configuration`, `Services`, `Microsoft Exchange`, `<YOUR ORGANIZATION>`, `Administrative Groups`, `Exchange Administrative Group`, `Servers`, `<SERVER NAME>`, `Information Store`, `<STORAGE GROUP NAME>`.  Then on the right hand pane, highlight the `Public Folder Store` and Delete it.